# 'dict' object has no attribute 'isdigit'

Tags: python, python-3.x

Есть такой вот скрипт

```
import json
import re


while True:
    print("1. Добавить новую запись")
    print("2. Поиск по записям")
    print("0. выйти из программы")
    cmd = input("Выберите пункт: ")


if cmd == "1":
  print ("Ввод данных")

  data = ''
  
  while (not data.isdigit()):
      data = {"ID": input('Введите ID: ')}
      print()
      if (not data.isdigit()): 
          print('ID необходимо указать цифрами!')
      else:
          print("")
          
  data = int(data)
  
  print ("Введите ФИО")

  data["Name"] = input()

  print ("Введите email")
  
  data["Email"] = input()

  print ("Введите номер телефона")

  data["Phone"] = input()
  

  with open("users.json", "a+") as file:
           file.write('\n')
           json.dump(data, file,ensure_ascii=False )


elif cmd == "2":
       print ("Введите данные для поиска")
       w = input()
       with open("Users.json") as fin:
           for s in fin.readlines():
              if s.find(w) > -1:
                print(s.strip())


elif cmd == "0":
                break
```

Скрипт смотрит есть ли файл в директории, если нет создает, если есть дописывает. Так же поиск по уже имеющимся данным. Не получается сделать, что бы в поле ввода ID был ограничен ввод только числовыми значениями. При этом если вводится не число, выдается предупреждение и возвращаемся к вводу ID заново

```
if cmd == "1":


print ("Ввод данных")

  data = ''

  while (not data.isdigit()):
      data = {"ID": input('Введите ID: ')}
      print()
      if (not data.isdigit()): 
          print('ID необходимо указать цифрами!')
      else:
          print("")

  data = int(data)
```

Вот на это участке вываливается ошибка

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\nkovalev\Desktop\Read-WriteReady.v0.3.1.py", line 24, in <module>
    if (not data.isdigit()):
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'isdigit'
```

Я так понимаю ругается на то, что словари не могут работать с модулем isdigit. Собственно вопрос - каким способом их можно подружить?
Так же буду очень благодарен если подскажите литературу для новичков, ибо python первый язык и это первый скрипт на нем, ранее подобным не занимался.

Comment: Не знаю зачем создали словарь для хранения переменной, но если сделали так, то обращайтесь к ней по ключу: data['ID'].isdigit()

Comment: _"Я так понимаю ругается на то, что словари не могут работать с модулем isdigit"_ - неправильно. Словарь чисто технически не может работать с функцией (это функция, а не модуль) is_digit, т.к. даже непонятно, что эта функция должна со словарем делать.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
  data = '' # <-- СТРОКА!

  while (not data.isdigit()):
      data = {"ID": input('Введите ID: ')} # <-- СЛОВАРЬ!!!
```

Просто не нужно разные переменные называть одинаковыми именами. У вас переменная `data` - это и **строка**, которую вы проверяете на `isdigit`, и **словарь**, содержащий ключ `ID`. Разделите эти сущности на две отдельные переменные - и не будет никаких проблем.

Ну, либо можете сразу сделать словарь и проверять его поле:

```
  data = {"ID": ''}

  while (not data["ID"].isdigit()):
      data = {"ID": input('Введите ID: ')}
```

Answer (score 0):

Первое - это ошибка с работой с типом данных словарь. Ключ - это по сути уникальное значение. Поэтому запускать `while` на один и тот же ключ, все-таки, является ошибкой. Но если уж очень хочется переписывать значение по ключу в цикле `while`, то можно что-то такое написать

```py
>>> data = {}
>>> while True:
...     id = input('Введите ID: ')
...     try:
...         id_int = int(id)
...         data["ID"] = id_int
...     except:
...         print("Input has to be integer")
...         break
...
Введите ID: 10
Введите ID: 20
Введите ID: 30
Введите ID: test
Input has to be integer
>>> data
{'ID': 30}
>>>
```

то есть ошибка в логике будет то, что сохраняется только последнее введенное значение

Answer (score -2):

Большое спасибо.
Решение

```
while (not data["ID"].isdigit()):
      data = {"ID": input('Введите ID: ')}
      if (not data["ID"].isdigit()): 
          print('ID необходимо указать цифрами!')
```

Помогло.

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Это новый вопрос.